# How to iterate json items in file in python and append it in list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, spacy

I am in new in json item manipulation. currently, I am doing an NLP project. I am building an NER model using Spacy. For annotation i have used dataturks.com annotation service. they have given a formatted JSON file 
the sample json items are like this. to be precise This json items are derived from  CSV file

```
{"content": "Canada,Airdrie,Alberta,M1B 0V1 ,418-555-0122","annotation":[{"label":["Phone Number"],"points":[{"start":32,"end":43,"text":"418-555-0122"}]},{"label":["Postal Code"],"points":[{"start":23,"end":29,"text":"M1B 0V1"}]},{"label":["Province"],"points":[{"start":15,"end":21,"text":"Alberta"}]},{"label":["City"],"points":[{"start":7,"end":13,"text":"Airdrie"}]},{"label":["Country"],"points":[{"start":0,"end":5,"text":"Canada"}]}],"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1545039231000,"last_updated_at":1545039231000,"sec_taken":50,"last_updated_by":"eODxmFU8wjPq8GJrmJtb0s7Wn9u1","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
{"content": "Canada,Barrie,Ontario,J2K 3C7 ,418-555-0135","annotation":[{"label":["Phone Number"],"points":[{"start":31,"end":42,"text":"418-555-0135"}]},{"label":["Postal Code"],"points":[{"start":22,"end":28,"text":"J2K 3C7"}]},{"label":["Province"],"points":[{"start":14,"end":20,"text":"Ontario"}]},{"label":["City"],"points":[{"start":7,"end":12,"text":"Barrie"}]},{"label":["Country"],"points":[{"start":0,"end":5,"text":"Canada"}]}],"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1545157658000,"last_updated_at":1545157658000,"sec_taken":21,"last_updated_by":"eODxmFU8wjPq8GJrmJtb0s7Wn9u1","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
{"content": "Canada,Brandon,Manitoba,B1A 2X0 ,418-555-0171","annotation":[{"label":["Phone Number"],"points":[{"start":33,"end":44,"text":"418-555-0171"}]},{"label":["Postal Code"],"points":[{"start":24,"end":30,"text":"B1A 2X0"}]},{"label":["Province"],"points":[{"start":15,"end":22,"text":"Manitoba"}]},{"label":["City"],"points":[{"start":7,"end":13,"text":"Brandon"}]},{"label":["Country"],"points":[{"start":0,"end":5,"text":"Canada"}]}],"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1545113770000,"last_updated_at":1545113770000,"sec_taken":27,"last_updated_by":"eODxmFU8wjPq8GJrmJtb0s7Wn9u1","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
```

My code snippet are

```
trainingfilename="C:/Users/codemen/Desktop/Timeseries Analytics/Canadianinfo.json"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
def ConvertDataturkToSpacy(trainingfilename):

    try:
        trainingData=[]
        lines=[]
        # reading file  and  formating  part
        with open(trainingfilename,'r') as f:
            lines=f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data=json.loads(line)
            #wprint(data)
            text=data['content']
            print("Mytext",text)
            entities=[]
            #print('entties',entities)
            for annotation in data['annotation']:
                #print("Here is the thing")
                points=annotation['points'][0] #single point annotation part
                #print(point)
                labels=annotation['label']
                print(labels)
                #print("type",type(labels))
                if not isinstance(labels,list):#handling both list of labels or single label
                    labels=[labels]
                   # print("instance",labels)

                for label in labels:
                    #dataturks indices are inclusive but spacy indices are not so dealing with it by adding  with +1
                    #print("Test here")
                    #print ("label")
                    #print("priniting label")
                    #print(label)
                    #print(" inside type",type(label))
                   # print(points['start'],points["end"]+1,label)
                    entities.append((points["start"],points["end"]+1,label))
                    #entities.append({points['start'],points["end"]+1,label})
                    #print("MyEntities",entities)


            trainingData.append((text,{"entities":entities}))
            return trainingData
            #print("TrainingData",trainingData)
            #print("Datatype",type(trainingData))
        #return trainingData
    except Exception as e:

        logging.exception("Unable to process item" + trainingfilename +"\n"+ "errror ="+str(e))
        return None




TrainingData=ConvertDataturkToSpacy(trainingfilename)
```

i have commented out my desired return statement if i keep it there it shows **None type object not iterable error**.  so for testing purpose i have put a return statement inside for loop which is actually returning a  list which is my first json item in my file

```
[('Canada,Airdrie,Alberta,M1B 0V1 ,418-555-0122', {'entities': [(32, 44, 'Phone Number'), (23, 30, 'Postal Code'), (15, 22, 'Province'), (7, 14, 'City'), (0, 6, 'Country')]})]
```

my desired list will be like this but with 1000 list elements like this. So I think i am not manipulating JSON properly. Kindly help me to solve this problem 
thank you

Comment: Two pointers here, take `trainingData=[] ` out of the try block and check. try replacing text=data['content'] with `text=data['content'].copy()`

Comment: thank you for your reply i tried but replacing text=data['content'].copy() gives me
'str' object has no attribute 'copy'. and putting  traiiningData[] out side try block didnt work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing the tasks a bit more may help locate your error. In other words, reading in the data and converting from json to a dict is conceptually separate from perusing the dicts and extracting/reformatting the info. You can test them separately and e.g. make sure your .json is actually loaded into memory.

For me, the following gives your indicated output and no errors (slightly modifying your code but keeping the same logic):

```
with open("places.json",'r') as fh:
    txt = fh.readlines()
    reps = [json.loads(l) for l in txt]

def extract_info(js):
  try:
    entities = []
    for e in js['annotation']:
        labs = e['label'] if isinstance(e['label'],list) else [e['label']]
        pts = e['points'][0]
        for lab in labs:
            entities.append((pts["start"],pts["end"]+1,lab))
    return (js['content'],{"entities" : entities})
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return None

# can make this an explicit for loop if needed for debugging purposes
training_data = [extract_info(r) for r in reps]

[('Canada,Airdrie,Alberta,M1B 0V1 ,418-555-0122',
  {'entities': [(32, 44, 'Phone Number'),
    (23, 30, 'Postal Code'),
    (15, 22, 'Province'),
    (7, 14, 'City'),
    (0, 6, 'Country')]}),
 ('Canada,Barrie,Ontario,J2K 3C7 ,418-555-0135',
  {'entities': [(31, 43, 'Phone Number'),
    (22, 29, 'Postal Code'),
    (14, 21, 'Province'),
    (7, 13, 'City'),
    (0, 6, 'Country')]}),
 ('Canada,Brandon,Manitoba,B1A 2X0 ,418-555-0171',
  {'entities': [(33, 45, 'Phone Number'),
    (24, 31, 'Postal Code'),
    (15, 23, 'Province'),
    (7, 14, 'City'),
    (0, 6, 'Country')]})]
```

It may be impossible to tell without further context what the problem is (somewhere there's an idiosyncrasy in the data formatting?), so it may be a matter of just accounting for more edge cases in your extraction process.

FWIW, the error you mention is easy to identify:

```
for x in None: print(x) # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. your solution works fine. i have got the list but  it leaves  Nonetype object is not iterable after executing TrainingData=[extractInfoJson(r) for r in rep]. but when i fit the training data on   NLP model again it is showing NoneType object is not iterable

Comment: I have figured two null value in annotation scope.  i have removed  it. and it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has some useful features for exploring json, assuming your json is valid, load it up with something like :

```
   import pandas as pd

   with open(filepath, 'r') as jdata:
       jobj =  json.load(jdata)
       df = pd.read_json(jobj)
       print(df)
```

Once you have the pandas data frame you can see the json as a table of rows and columns 
and can select a subset of rows and columns to isolate the data you need or if nothing else to get a clearer picture of the data

Comment: Thank you for your reply  i have tried  but come up to this error    File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

JSONDecodeError: Extra data